# How to call a Java applet callback function from native C/C++ code using JNI.

Tags: java, c++, c, applet, java-native-interface

How to call a Java applet callback function from native C/C++ code using JNI. Please let me know how can this be done correctly. Please any code snippet would be helpful.

```
// Java Applet code

public class TestApp extends Applet {

    private native void TestMethod(int nValue);

    public void callback(int nValue) {
            // DISPLAY SOME MESSAGE FROM NATIVE DLL RECEIVED

    }

     static {
        System.load("c/temp/TestDll.dll");
  }
}
```

// TestDll.cpp

```
JNIEnv *g_env;
jobject g_object;
jmethodID g_method;




   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
    Java_Callbacks_TestMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint Value)
    {
        jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
        jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", "(I)V");      

        g_env = env;
        g_Object = obj;
        g_method = mid
    }

        // Cannot be called within the above function
    void TestDllCallbackFunction (int nValue)
    {

            // This is where i want to call the Java callback function… would the below work???
        (*g_env)->CallVoidMethod(g_env, g_object, g_method, ((jint)Value);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Basically it is correct, the way you do it. Beside the fact that you should not store java objects in native global variables. You cannot assure that the GC will not delete them.

Comment: How can i call the Java callback function in the local native function if i dont have a reference to the current java objects. Please describe by giving a code example.Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html. What you want are global references to your object.

Comment: Thanks for the response: mKaes. I did made the object a global reference but the flow doesn't come out of CallVoidMethod(). Please let me know if you have any clue to it. Please see below the code as there is not enough space here to post it with this comment

Comment: JNIEnv *g_env;
jobject g_object;
jmethodID g_method;
<pre><code>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_Callbacks_TestMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint Value)
{
    g_env = env;
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);

    g_Object = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(obj); // HERE

    g_method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", "(I)V"); 

}

// Cannot be called within the above function
void TestDllCallbackFunction (int nValue)
{
 Log("IN");

 nValue = 5; 
 (*g_env)->CallVoidMethod(g_env, g_object, g_method, ((jint)nValue);
 
 Log("OUT"); // The log statement NEVER gets executed. 

}

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider another solution as an alternative to callbacks from C++ to Java:

- Create an extra Java thread to wait for a response from C++
- Let that Java thread call a C++ function that blocks on a condition variable (or similar, depending on your OS) until the response is ready to be returned.
- When you want to call the callback, let the above C++ function have the data and signal the condition variable. Then it can return the data.

Callbacks through JNI can certainly be done, but I think they add unnecessary complexity. Using the above method you can keep things more nicely separated IMHO.